# VBA - UDF result not showing correctly

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a user-defined function in VBA that counts the number of cells in a given range that have certain fill color applied as part of a conditional format.

As I devised it, this function would require two arguments: 1) the range of cells to be counted if they have a certain fill color, and 2) a cell with the desired fill color applied.

The following function seems to work fine when I check the Result preview in the Function Arguments box (Shift+F3), and when I F9 the formula in the cell, but not when I input the cell in the worksheet and press Enter (in this case, it just seems to be counting the number of cells in the range without checking if it effectively has the adequate fill color).

```
Function CountCcolor(Cells As Range, Color As Range)

Application.Volatile True

Dim Rng As Range

On Error Resume Next

For Each Rng In Cells
    If Rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = Color.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color Then
    CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    End If
Next

End Function
```

Any ideas of what may be causing this strange behavior?

Hope I have made myself clear, and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: DisplayFormat isn't available in a UDF

Comment: `DisplayFormat` doesn't work in UDFs, but there's a workaround demonstrated in the linked thread.

Comment: Thanks both for your kind and prompt help, will certainly check that thread